# Wordpress mix results of two queries

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a little problem! I want to mix the results of two queries! I want them to be mixed in date order!

With the actual query, they show one after the other.

Does anyone get the solution?

```
<?php

$loop = new WP_Query( array (
    'post_type' => array('videos','photos'),
    'category_name' => 'une',
) );

while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php

$loop = new WP_Query( array (
    'post_type' => array('spectacles'),
    'category_name' => 'une-en',
) );

while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>


<?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: You might try [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135820/merge-2-args-in-one-wp-query-and-order-it-by-date).

Comment: Thanks @showdev i found the solution !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried combining the query into one instead of two? So you'd only have one query, which is

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array (
    'post_type'   => array('spectacles', 'videos', 'photos'),
    'category__in' => array(1, 2), // IDs of the categories
    'orderby'     => 'date'
) );
```

EDIT:

If this does not work with the categories as you mentioned, you can use this workaround:

```
$ids_a = new WP_Query( array (
    'post_type' => array('videos','photos'),
    'category_name' => 'une',
    'fields' => 'ids'
) );

$ids_b = new WP_Query( array (
    'post_type' => array('spectacles'),
    'category_name' => 'une-en',
    'fields' => 'ids'
) );

$ids = array_merge($ids_a, $ids_b);

$loop = new WP_Query( array (
    'post__in' => $ids,
    'orderby' => 'date'
) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work because it also show the post_type videos from the category une-en ! I want to show specific category from specific post_type !

Comment: Have you created categories with the same names for each of the post types, or are they all hooked up to the same set of categories? If you have categories with the same names, you can use the ID to differentiate them (the code in my post). However if you only have one set of categories, we need another solution

Comment: They are not in the same set ! They are in two different part, one in french 'une', one in english 'une-en' ! Maybe my construction of the system is not good... :(

Comment: I have updated my original post with a new method if you have trouble with the category IDs

Comment: It doesn't work :( I think i've found a solution, i'm gonna duplicate the posts in the both language it will be more simple to show what i want after ! Thanks for your help !